# Plot the density of a matrix

Tags: matlab

Good day,

In Matlab I have got a matrix which is very sparse. Now I would like to plot the 'density' of the matrix. Let's say I have a matrix A:

```
A = [3 0 0
     0 2 0
     0 0 1];
```

Now the plot should look something like:

```
x  
  x  
    x
```

So there should be a dot (or something else) at each location (row, column) in which matrix A has got a nonzero value.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Could you include a code snippet for us to look at? People are most likely to help if you show that you put some effort in too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`spy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spy.html) is what you need:

```
% taken from MatLab documentation
B = bucky;
spy(B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like this:

```ml
subs = zeros(0,2);
for ind = [find(A)']
    [r,c] = ind2sub(size(A), ind);
    subs = [subs; [r,c]];
end

scatter(subs(:,2), subs(:,1));
set(gca,'YDir','Reverse')
xlim([1 size(A,2)])
ylim([1 size(A,1)])
```

Which, for the matrix A:

```
 0     1     0     1     1
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     1     1
 0     0     1     1     0
```

Gives you the following scatter plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
A=[3 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 0 1];
imagesc(A)
```